# How to decompose a JSON with jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a file with an array of JSON:

```
[
  {
    "names": [
      "name1"
    ],
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "names": [
      "name1",
      "name2"
    ],
    "id": "2"
  }
]
```

and I would like to create a new file with each JSON of previous JSON array, broken down by its field "origin", like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "name1"
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "id": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "name2",
    "id": "2"
  }
]
```

I use jq version 1.6 in a bash script.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Just to note, "JSON" is not a synonym for "object". Both objects and arrays are different kinds of JSON values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
jq '[.[] | .names[] as $n | {id: .id, name: $n}]' input.json > output.json
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
map({id, name: .names[]})
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/-L9VVZMAvdk)</sup>